# LibreOffice Writer: get contents of the next cell to the found one

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-basic

I need to find some text in the Writer table, then get contents of the cell right of the found text into the variable. Text is found successfully with this code:

```
Sub get_contr_num
    dim oDoc as Object
    dim oFound as Object
    dim oDescriptor
    dim oCursor as Object
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oDescriptor = oDoc.createSearchDescriptor()
    oDescriptor.SearchString = "Contract *No"
    oDescriptor.SearchRegularExpression = true
    oFound=oDoc.FindFirst(oDescriptor)
End Sub
```

Now I need to get contents of the right cell. As I understand, `oFound` is an object of `XTextRange`, and I need `XCellRange` with row and column parameters. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From section 7.1.2 of [Andrew Pitonyak, 2015](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php):

> The TextRange object has a TextTable property and a Cell property.
>   These two properties are not empty if the text range is contained in a
>   text table cell.

Here is example code.

```
cellname_found = oFound.Cell.CellName
cellname_right = Chr(Asc(Left(cellname_found, 1))+1) & Right(cellname_found, 1)
oTable = oFound.TextTable
oCell_right = oTable.getCellByName(cellname_right)
```

It would be easier if [CellProperties](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/CellProperties.html) gave row and column numbers instead of a name.  Apparently, it does not, so it is necessary to use [string manipulation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Strings_(Runtime_Library)) to parse the `CellName` property.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after modifying: `cellname_right = Chr(Asc(Left(cellname_found, 1))+1) + Mid(cellname_found, 2)`. Because while columns don't often exceed the range A-Z, row numbers in my case contain more than one digit.